# Sort List<T> with integer property using C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I want to sort my List, where T is Products.
The List may contains elememts with duplicate **ReportSeqId**. I want to sort it according to **ReportSeqId**.

But the criteria is that if the *ReportSeqId = 0* then it should come last.

INPUT :

```
new ilistProd<Products>()
{
    new Products(0, Report1, SSR),
    new Products(2, Report2, SBO),
    new Products(0, Report3, PST),
    new Products(3, Report4, ABR),
    new Products(1, Report5, OSS),
    new Products(0, Report6, TCP),
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
new ilistProd<Products>()
{
    new Products(1, Report5, OSS),
    new Products(2, Report2, SBO),
    new Products(3, Report4, ABR),
    new Products(0, Report3, PST),
    new Products(0, Report6, TCP),
    new Products(0, Report1, SSR)
}
```

Below is my code :

```
public class Products
{
    //ctor
    public SDVar(int xiReportSeqId, string xiReportName, string xiProduct)
    {
      this.ReportSeqId = xiReportSeqId;
      this.ReportName = xiReportName;
      this.Product = xiProduct;
    }

   public int ReportSeqId {get; set;}
   public string ReportName {get; set;}
   public string Product {get; set;}
}


public class SDVar
{
    //ctor
public SDVar()
{
}

public void DoSort(ref List<Products> ilistProd)
{
    ilistProd.Sort(delegate(Products x, Products y)
    {
        if (x.ReportSeqId == 0)
        {
            if (y.ReportSeqId == 0) 
            { 
                return 0; 
            }
            return -1;
        }
        return x.ReportSeqId.CompareTo(y.ReportSeqId);
    }       
}
 }
```

Comment: Did you try to swap `-1` with `1`? (side question: why `ref List<Products>`? In any case you don't replace input variable with a new list)

Comment: Actual code involve much work after sorting. This is just to present an example. You may consider return ilistProd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
list.Sort(delegate(Products x, Products y)
{
    if(x.ReportSeqId == 0)
        return 1;       
    if(y.ReportSeqId == 0)
        return -1;
    return x.ReportSeqId.CompareTo(y.ReportSeqId);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally my preferred solution would be to add an extra property (e.g. SortIndex) which can be used in either Linq, or in a sort delegate (where id 0 would return an int.maxvalue), but to get the existing code to work, you should do an extra check to see of the second id is 0, if the first id is not:

```
if (x.ReportSeqId == 0)
{
    if (y.ReportSeqId == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
else if (y.ReportSeqId == 0) 
    return -1;
return x.ReportSeqId.CompareTo(y.ReportSeqId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to implement IComparable

```
public class Product : IComparable<Product>
{
    private int ReportSeqId = 0;

    public int CompareTo(Product other)
    {
        if (ReportSeqId == 0 || other == null) return 1;

        if (other.ReportSeqId == 0) return - 1;

        return ReportSeqId - other.ReportSeqId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `LINQ`:

```
products = products.OrderBy(p => p.ReportSeqId == 0 ? Int32.MaxValue : p.ReportSeqId).ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry to add one more thing. I am using .Net Framework 2.0, so LINQ may not be the choice for me.